# Error installing Apache Airflow 2.6.1 on Python 3.8.7

Tags: python, airflow

1. I am on Python 3.8.7
2. I tried running with respect to my python version below

`- pip install 'apache-airflow==2.6.1' \   \--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.1/constraints-3.8.txt"`

3. can't seem to figure out why I am getting an error, very confused on what the error might be

   I believe the error is related to some subprocess error? But keep digging into a rabbit whole of different related issues. Please let me know if any additional information is required

````
dsor@DESKTOP-A649DRD MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Files/Code/airflow_tutorial
$ pip install 'apache-airflow==2.6.1'  --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.1/constraints-3.8.txt"
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:/users/dsor/desktop/files/code/airflow_tutorial/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
Collecting apache-airflow==2.6.1
  Using cached apache_airflow-2.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (12.1 MB)
Collecting alembic<2.0,>=1.6.3 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached alembic-1.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
Collecting argcomplete>=1.10 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached argcomplete-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting asgiref (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting attrs>=22.1.0 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting blinker (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached blinker-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting cattrs>=22.1.0 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached cattrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting colorlog<5.0,>=4.0.2 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached colorlog-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting configupdater>=3.1.1 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached ConfigUpdater-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting connexion[flask]>=2.10.0 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached connexion-2.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting cron-descriptor>=1.2.24 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached cron_descriptor-1.3.0.tar.gz (29 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting croniter>=0.3.17 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached croniter-1.3.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=0.9.3 (from apache-airflow==2.6.1)
  Using cached cryptography-40.0.2.tar.gz (625 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [53 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools!=60.9.0,>=40.6.0
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting cffi>=1.12
        Using cached cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [26 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Users/dsor/Desktop/Files/Code/airflow_tutorial/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:/Users/dsor/Desktop/Files/Code/airflow_tutorial/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "C:/Users/dsor/Desktop/Files/Code/airflow_tutorial/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return hook(config_settings)
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires      
            self.run_setup()
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
            super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
            exec(code, locals())
          File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
          File "<string>", line 105, in uses_msvc
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/config.py", line 223, in try_compile
            self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/config.py", line 128, in _compile  
            self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile    
            self.initialize()
          File "C:/Users/dsor/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-17uudowo/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize 
            raise DistutilsPlatformError(
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
     
      See above for output.
     
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
(py_env) ```
````